# I am not able to compile,libraries missing

Tags: arduino-uno

this was the error  message
Arduino: 1.6.7 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

Sketch uses 1,068 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 11 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,037 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\.\COM17": The semaphore timeout period has expired.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
**Invalid library found in C:\Users\nehal\Documents\Arduino\libraries\leddelay: C:\Users\nehal\Documents\Arduino\libraries\leddelay
Invalid library found in C:\Users\nehal\Documents\Arduino\libraries\sketch_jan16c: C:\Users\nehal\Documents\Arduino\libraries\sketch_jan16c
Invalid library found in C:\Users\nehal\Documents\Arduino\libraries\leddelay: C:\Users\nehal\Documents\Arduino\libraries\leddelay
Invalid library found in C:\Users\nehal\Documents\Arduino\libraries\sketch_jan16c: C:\Users\nehal\Documents\Arduino\libraries\sketch_jan16c**

This report would have more information with
  "Show verbose output during compilation"
  enabled in File > Preferences.
 **What should I do?**

Comment: You have two distinct issues here, one critical and one probably annoyance-level.  The critical one is that your chosen serial port is not available - maybe the board moved, or something else is trying to talk to it.  Separately, you seem to have some garbage in the libraries folder, maybe a sketch inappropriately saved there.   The IDE is complaining about that, but not refusing to compile on account of it in the way your title implies - you do not actually have a compile error.